# Is it possible to own more than 10 cars in Grand Theft Auto online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

As the title says - is it possible to own more than 10 cars in Grand Theft Auto online?

The largest garage you can currently buy holds 10 cars, and you can only own one garage at a time.

What happens if you buy more than 10 cars? Are they still accessible (via your Mechanic)?

I'm only interested in non-exploit methods for owning more than 10 cars as I don't want any of my vehicles disappearing when the exploit is fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number has been increasing over time and as far as I can tell it now depends which version you are playing.

As far as I can tell [in the PS3/XB360 edition you now get up to 3 properties](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/9mn54s/how_many_properties_is_one_allowed_to_own/) with up to 10 cars each for a total of 30. In the PS4/XBONE/PC edition you get up to 5 regular properties with up to 10 cars each for a total of 50.

But it doesn't end there, Rockstar keep adding new property types to the PS4/XBONE/PC version of GTA online, many of which come with options for vehicle storage. Adding up the numbers on to the [GTA wiki](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Personal_Vehicles) I count a total of 189 slots that can be used for regular cars (plus others that are motorbike only or reserved for special vehicles).

If you run out of slots in a garage when trying to add a vehicle to it (either a newly stolen vehicle, a newly bought vehicle, or a vehicle moved from another garage) you will be asked which of the current vehicles in the garage you want to get rid of to make room.

Answer (score 2):

In 1.13 they will add the feature to own multiple garages, and therefore, more than 10 vehicles.

http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/52245/GTA-Online-The-High-Life-Update-Coming-Next-Week-Tuesday

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, 10 seems to be the max. It all depends on your property's storage capacity, but purchasing one more car than you can hold (say, 11 when you have space for 10) will force you to remove an existing vehicle. I'm hoping that they will introduce the ability to have multiple properties, but for now you're limited to one.