# Is there enough storage place for all vehicles in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I want to know if it is possible to own every vehicle in GTA Online, those vehicles you can buy on SSA Superautos, Legendary Motorsports, Warstock Cache & Carry, Pedal and Metal, Benny's Original Motor Works - so basically all vehicles which are storable in garages, is there enough space for all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can currently own a maximum of [189 garage spaces for personal vehicles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158700/is-it-possible-to-own-more-than-10-cars-in-grand-theft-auto-online), not including owned aircraft, seacraft, or vehicles imported via Merryweather or Pegasus.

There are [337 vehicles currently available](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vehicles_in_GTA_V) in Grand Theft Auto Online. Ignoring the incredible cost of purchasing all of these vehicles you will not have the capacity to store them all.